# Android: EditText not updates when typing text

Tags: android, android-edittext, customdialog

I have following in my app:

layout/dialog_edit_group.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/dlgEditGroup"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText android:id="@+id/txtGroup"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="Group Name"
          android:inputType="text"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:editable="true"/>
```

my activity (onCreateDialog method):

```
        ...
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_group, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.dlgEditGroup));
        EditText txtGroup = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
        txtGroup.setFocusable(true);
        builder.setView(layout);
        return builder.create();
```

When dialog appears and I try to type text - edit text not updates. Keyboard shows that keys are pressed (I see keyboard hints - I use gingerbread keyboard), but nothing changes in edittext. What I need to do?

**UPD: see video with issue: [youtu.be/XOSXDSZvisI](http://youtu.be/XOSXDSZvisI)**

Comment: addition: on each key press in logcat adding next:

`WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(2517): commitText on inactive InputConnection`

Answer (score 3):

**The main reason behind this is maybe in your manifest file**

The main problem is with this line in your manifest file:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated = "false">
```

To make the text you have typed to be updated in the editText field remove this line in your manifest file:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated = "false"
```

(or)

Modify the line as:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated = "true"
```

I am answering this question late, but I hope that maybe it would be useful for who are still facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the EditText to focusable AFTER adding the view?

Comment: yes, nothing changed. but in logcat now

`WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(2629): sendKeyEvent on inactive InputConnection`

Answer (score 0):

`setFocusable(true);` just makes the widget focusable and in the case of `EditText` is focusable by default.

Try [requestFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29) instead.

Comment: nothing changed for me ( both on lg optimus one and my captivate

Answer (score 0):

I have got this error on my HTC Desire too, but when I wait about 1-2 min, all edittext work normal after some system os log. So, I think problem is not your code.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for this answer, I solved my problem by setting color of EditText to BLACK

```
editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```